# I am Running simple JQuery with Keyup event and animation but my animation is not working, why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation

I have this simple JQuery addition program with animation on keyup event of 2nd #num2 input type text, I am getting proper answer but animation is not showing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#num2').keyup(function() {

    let num1 = parseFloat($('#num1').val());
    let num2 = parseFloat($('#num2').val());

    if (!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {
      let sum = num1 + num2;
      $('#add').text(sum);
      $('#add').slideDown(4000);
    } else {
      $('#add').text("Please enter valid numbers");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Enter first number">
<input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Enter second number">
<h3 id="add"></h3><br/>
<h3 id="sub"></h3><br/>
<h3 id="mul"></h3><br/>
<h3 id="div"></h3><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to display the addition result with the animation effect of `slideDown`. The issue I am seeing here is that when you add the text to the `h3`, it's already down the `input` elements. Sliding it down will not take it anywhere else. If you want the animation of `slideDown` to work, probably, you can `slideUp` first and then slide it down.

I have added `h3` for showing the error because using the same `h3` for showing the `sum` and the `error message` may not give you the right effect (at least in my opinion; I welcome others to correct me here)

I tried to show here how it will work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Addition using jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="num1" placeholder="Enter first number">
  <input type="number" id="num2" placeholder="Enter second number">
  <h3 id="add"></h3><br/>
  <h3 id="error"></h3>
  <h3 id="sub"></h3><br/>
  <h3 id="mul"></h3><br/>
  <h3 id="div"></h3><br/>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#num2').keyup(function() {
        $('#error').text('');
        let num1 = parseFloat($('#num1').val());
        let num2 = parseFloat($('#num2').val());
        $('#add').slideUp();
        if (!isNaN(num1) && !isNaN(num2)) {
          let sum = num1 + num2;
          $('#add').text(sum);
          $('#add').slideDown();
        } else {         
          $('#error').text("Please enter valid numbers");
        }
    });
    
    });
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the element is visible at all time, `slideDown()` won't give any visible changes.

Make sure to either do a `slideUp()` or `hide()` at the start of your keyup event, so that when your `slideDown()` happens, it can add the sliding effect you are looking for.

Also, add `display: none` to your elements in which you are going to show the output.